# Trigonometric contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\sin\theta} d\theta\quad a>b>0$$

---

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{a+\frac{b}{2i}(z-z^{-1})} \frac{dz}{iz}$$

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{2i}{2ia+b(z-z^{-1})} \frac{dz}{iz}$$

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{2}{2iza+bz^2-b} dz$$

$$2iz_0a+bz_0^2-b=0$$

$$z_0=\frac{-2ia\pm\sqrt{-4^2+4b^2}}{2b}$$

$$z_0=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{bi}$$

where only $z_0=\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{bi}$ is within $C$.

So $Res(z_0) = \frac{-2b}{-2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$

So the integral is $\frac{2\pi bi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$

But this is wrong. The $bi$ should not be there. However I cannot see what I'm missing here? I also checked $Res(0)$ for order 1 and it was equal to $0$.

Comment: $$bz^2+2ia z-b=0\implies z=\frac{-ai\pm\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{b}$$

Comment: @dr-mv I put it in the form $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ as that is the final form of the answer. Your zero seems equivalent to mine. Just formatted differently?!

Comment: @dr-mv I realized I had a typo. But that does not help me. My final answer is still wrong.

Comment: @user1952009 What would be the reason for that? Also it seems like it would end up being 0 then.

Comment: I arrived at $2\pi/\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.

Comment: @dr-mv Yeah that is the answer I need. Where did we diverge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral $I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a+b\sin \theta}\,d\theta$ is simply $2\pi i$ times $2/b$ times the residue of $z^2+i 2(a/b) z-1$ at $z=i\left(-\frac ab +\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}\right)$.  Thus, we have

$$I=(2\pi i)\frac2b \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$

Comment: @dr-mv This is fine. I just messed up the factoring

Comment: That's a common error.  You had the correct concept, but made only a careless error. ;-)) Well done otherwise! - Mark